# How to check if a list procceeds another list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to create an argument that succeeds when a list proceeds another list.

For example ?-proceed_list([1,2],[2]). Yes or True(whatever the compiler).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you rephrase or clarify your question?

Comment: Yes no problem. I want to make an argument, lets name it proceed_list(X,Y), which succeeds when the list Y proceeds list X.In other words list Y has items that are after list X.For example [1,2,3] proceeds [1,2]. For example if we ask prolog ?-proceed_list([1,2],[2]) then the answer should be Yes. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is hard to parse. As aqua commented, you should rephrase it. For what it's worth, I understand your example that you want to check whether the second list `[2]` is the tail of the first `[1,2]` (i.e., "proceed" in the sense of "continue"). If that's what you want, then this should work:

```
proceed_list(L1, L2) :-
    once(append(_, L2, L1)).
```

Comment: Thank you so much twinterer. I will try be more specific with my questions in the future.

Comment: @Pantheo: btw if you liked twinterer's answerer, you can click the check sign of his answer to accept it :)

Comment: be O(1) as a difference list on tail-side insertion sadly :(((